# Can I build a SPA using lightning web component framework outside Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, sales-cloud, web, html-template-directives

I want to build a single page web app (not in Salesforce). Just like when we write html using Angular, you import JS and CSS (from Angular or react framework CDN). Similarly is it possible to do such a thing using LWC. And I want to implement LWC (i.e. both JS and HTML) not the SLDS css.

Please advise, if anyone went through such effort or provide some link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use LWC OSS to use LWC outside salesforce.

Note that you might not recieve the benefits of Locker when using outside Salesforce Platform

Here's the link:
https://lwc.dev/